# how do I programmatically upload pictures to facebook?

Tags: facebook, asp.net, facebook-graph

Ok, so here was my first question:
[How do I allow visitors on my site to share my photos on their facebook news feed?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/how-do-i-allow-visitors-on-my-site-to-share-my-photos-on-their-facebook-news-feed)

After implementing it I realized what I really want is a link that uploads the image as a photo to their photo album.

How would I got about getting an image on my site to upload to their photo album when they click on a facebook icon next to the image?

Any thoughts at all are appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

To share an image in a user's stream can be as simple as adding a correctly formatted link.  However, I'm fairly sure that to upload to a user's album by clicking a button you'd have to make use of Facebook's API.  While that's not a detailed answer, I have unfortunately never worked with it personally, so I don't have an example implementation.

The place to start with Facebook's API documentation is http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/.  I also found this blog post whose link I can't post because of the limit, but it uses PHP anyway.

For .NET type stuff I found http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/developing-with-facebook-api-sdk-w-asp.net.  I can't provide a link to the SDK I found due to the limit.

Comment: PHP example http://daipratt.co.uk/facebook-api-upload-photo/

Comment: SDK link http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post from Facebook on how to do it: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498

Comment: You can now upload using a URL, which could be the one on your site. So it's even easier now: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/